# SCP returns error (msgErr28) while classifying landuse (QGIS 3.20, SCP 7.10)

Tags: qgis, python, scp, scipy

I use the (great) SCP 7.10 for classifying forests with Sentinel 2 scenes. After post processing and creating the ROIs and Signatures, I start the classification (preview or band processing classification) and get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/map/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/SemiAutomaticClassificationPlugin/maininterface/classificationTab.py", line 121, in runClassificationAction
    self.runClassification(bandSetNumber = bndStN, algorithmFilesCheck = algFilesCheck, reportCheck = report, vectorConversion = vector, useMacroclass = macroclass, useLcs = useLcs, useLcsAlgorithm = useLcsAlgorithm, LCSLeaveUnclassified = leaveUnclassified, maskCheckBox = maskC, maskPath = maskPath)
  File "/home/map/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/SemiAutomaticClassificationPlugin/maininterface/classificationTab.py", line 206, in runClassification
    ok, cOut, mOut, opOut = self.runAlgorithm(algorithmName, img, sLMP, cfg.clssPth, useMacroclass, algRasterPath, 0, None, cfg.rasterCompression, bandSetNumber, classificationOptions)
  File "/home/map/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/SemiAutomaticClassificationPlugin/maininterface/classificationTab.py", line 577, in runAlgorithm
    o = cfg.utls.multiProcessRaster(rasterPath = tPMD, signatureList = signatureList, functionBand = 'Yes', functionRaster = cfg.utls.classificationMultiprocess, algorithmName = algorithmName, nodataValue = -999, macroclassCheck = macroclassCheck,classificationOptions = classificationOptions, functionBandArgument = cfg.multiAddFactorsVar, functionVariable = cfg.bandSetsList[bandSetNumber][6], progressMessage = cfg.QtWidgetsSCP.QApplication.translate('semiautomaticclassificationplugin', 'Classification'), virtualRaster = 'Yes', compress = compress, compressFormat = 'LZW')
  File "/home/map/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/SemiAutomaticClassificationPlugin/core/utils.py", line 5364, in multiProcessRaster
    res = r[0].get()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 771, in get
    raise self._value
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'msgErr28'
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved by new SCP Version 7.10.1! Just released now!